# Editable Combobox dont get item wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox that I set `isEditable = true` but when I press Down arrow from keyboard I get this message

> MoalemYar.DataClass.DataTransferObjects+StudentsDto

Instead of my selected item, this is my combobox

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="cmbEditStudent"
    IsEditable="True"
    SelectedValue="{Binding LName}"
    SelectedValuePath="Id">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LName}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" - " />
                <TextBlock Text="نام پدر(" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FName}" />
                <TextBlock Text=")" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Check if your properties `Name`/`LName`/`RName` are accessible from outside the class (aka are `internal` or `public`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this hope it will helps you
    <ComboBox Height="25" Margin="80,12,12,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}" IsEditable="True" TextSearch.TextPath="StudentName">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: is there any way to bind multiple in TextSearch.TextPath? for example TextSearch.TextPath="StudentName, StudentLName"

Answer (score 1):

By default, the first item in a combo box is selected by the down arrow, then you can press up/down arrows keys to change the selected item accordingly.

Try the following code.

**In XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox
        x:Name="cmbEditStudent"
        IsTextSearchEnabled="True"   
        TextSearch.TextPath = "Name"
        IsEditable="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding StudentsList}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LName}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" - " />
                    <TextBlock Text="نام پدر(" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FName}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=")" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

    <TextBox Width="200" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

**In its View Model**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Student> studentsList = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
    public ObservableCollection<Student> StudentsList
    {
        get { return studentsList; }
        set
        {
            studentsList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Student selectedStudent;
    public Student SelectedStudent
    {
        get { return selectedStudent; }
        set
        {
            selectedStudent = value;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        StudentsList.Add(new Student("Paul", "LName1", "FName1"));
        StudentsList.Add(new Student("Alex", "LName2", "FName2"));
        StudentsList.Add(new Student("Steve", "LName3", "FName3"));
    }

    #region Notify Property
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propName))
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Student Class**

```
 public class Student : NotifiableBase
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string lName;
    public string LName
    {
        get { return lName; }
        set
        {
            lName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string fName;
    public string FName
    {
        get { return fName; }
        set
        {
            fName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Student(string name, string lName, string fName)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.fName = fName;
    }
}
```

**NotifiableBase**

```
public class NotifiableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propName))
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }));
        }
    }
}
```